# How can a string be imported as a Python module bound to a local name?

Tags: python, string, import, module, local

I have a string that contains the text of a Python module. I want to import this as a Python module bound to a local name.

I can import it globally in a way such as the following:

```
exec myModuleString in globals()
```

What I want to do is import it bound to a local name, much as in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
```

How could I do this?

Comment: The equivalent of `import numpy as np` using a string as the name would be `np = __import__("numpy")`. There is a wrapper for this in [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html).

Comment: I can see the overlap, but I'm not sure this question is exactly a duplicate. The emphasis in this question is the binding to a local variable. I'll leave the decision to the wisdom of the moderators.